# Compare table columns based on their relative position

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a problem with comparing two selects in PostgreSQL. I'm executing these selects by JDBC, then create new tables by inserting data from the result set to new table. I do it because I want to avoid columns with same name like "count". Then I have to compare data in these tables.

The problem is that these tables should be same if there is same data with different order of columns. For example, if there are 3 columns (1, 2, 3) in tables `t1` and `t2` these tables are the same if `t1.1 = t2.2` and `t1.2 = t2.1` and `t1.3 = t2.3`.

Comment: Are there any duplicate rows in either table?  And if there are, how do you want to deal with this scenario?  `Table1 has 2 copies of a row, Table2 has the same row, but only 1 copy of it`

Comment: There is no order. Columns have names. Please explain what you intend to do.

Answer (score 2):

The **order of columns** within a row is determined at the time of creation. If you do a

```
SELECT * FROM tbl;
```

or

```
TABLE tbl;
```

you get the column order you created the table with. If you name columns in your `SELECT` you get your columns in your explicit order.

You must **always** spell out the columns you use for an operation like yours. It could break if you alter the order of columns in one of your tables later. Do not rely on `*`.

The **order of rows** in a `SELECT` is **indeterminate** as long as you don't include an `ORDER BY` clause. If you want a specific order you have to `ORDER BY` a primary or unique column (or unique combination of columns). If you order by a non-unique set of columns, the rows within groups of the same key are again in indeterminate order.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl
ORDER BY <unique column or set of oclumns>;
```

Read the manual on the [ORDER BY clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY).